# You need to use a different version code for your APK or Android App Bundle because you already have one with version code 1

Tags: android

I want to published a update version of my android apps.

When I upload it give me this warning.

Lot of article show If I add version number in my manifest file it work.

in my case it not still working.

Comment: You have to update your versionCode inside build.gradle, not in manifest file.

Comment: @hardartcore Where I will write it.

Comment: As I said, `build.gradle` file

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Every time you build a new apk or bundle to publish to the store you need tu upgrade the versionCode in app level build.gradle file. Usually it's increase 1 by 1. In your case upgrade to 2.

```
versionCode 2
```

look at this : https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning

```
android 
{ 
    compileSdkVersion 28 defaultConfig 
    { 
        applicationId "example.xxz.abc"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1  <-------------- CHANGE HERE
        versionName "1.0"
    } 
    buildTypes 
    { 
        release 
        { 
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        } 
    } 
} 

dependencies 
{ 
    implementation fileTree(include 
                            : [ '*.jar' ], dir 
                            : 'libs') 
    ...
}
```

Comment: in you src/app/build.gradle you have this line

Comment: I've noticed I even need to do this when a version fails to get published for some reason (wrong architecture or doesn't target a high enough API level)

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Just enter a new version code number which is greater than the one you have previously used

Answer (score 0):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.deltastatepensionsbureau.helpdesk"
      minSdk 21
      targetSdk 32
      versionCode 2  <-------------------- For ionic change it to whole number 
        versionName '1.1'  <-------------- Just any increment will do
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        aaptOptions {
             // Files and dirs to omit from the packaged assets dir, modified to accommodate modern web apps.
             // Default: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/282e181b58cf72b6ca770dc7ca5f91f135444502/tools/aapt/AaptAssets.cpp#61
            ignoreAssetsPattern '!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:.*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir{
        dirs '../capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/src/main/libs', 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$androidxAppCompatVersion"
    implementation project(':capacitor-android')
    testImplementation "junit:junit:$junitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$androidxJunitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$androidxEspressoCoreVersion"
    implementation project(':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins')
}

apply from: 'capacitor.build.gradle'

try {
    def servicesJSON = file('google-services.json')
    if (servicesJSON.text) {
        apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    logger.info("google-services.json not found, google-services plugin not applied. Push Notifications won't work")
}
```